# Make regex not match the last word

Tags: javascript, regex

**Question:**

How do I capture all words in a `string` except the last word unless it's followed by `,` or `.`?

i.e. for `jumps over the lazy dog` capture `jumps` `over` `the` `lazy`. But for `jumps over the lazy dog.` the `dog` also has to be captured.

NOTE: this is JavaScript regex.

---

**What I have done:**

`\([\w']+\b)\g` captures all the words, however it also captures the `dog` without the punctuation. (I used `[\w']` to include apostrophes in words).

I suspect the answer has something to do with `$`?

Comment: This sounds like a job for negative lookahead.

Comment: What about `\w+\b(?!$)`?

Comment: How about `jumps over the lazy dog;` should `dog` be captured or not?

Comment: @ctwheels that works. Thanks! If you want to put this as an answer I will accept it. If not I will delete the question in 1 hour.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo done :)

Comment: And a big -1 for you for not knowing the right answer and for picking the wrong answer. If you need examples of why it's wrong, let me know.

Comment: You should have down-voted and comment on the wrong answer instead of posting a passive aggressive comment on the question itself. How would I know which answer is correct when I'm asking the question in the first place? Since you mentioned, how is the first answer wrong.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo - Unless you're making a general statement, you have to prepend the @+username to reply to a specific comment. If you're talking to me, here I am a day later and happenstance this Q. again. `How would I know which answer is correct` A: it's you're responsibility to insure it's correct, since nobody else can mark an answer. Some people might try to use the exact solution, only to find out it's junk, further cluttering up SO with another exact question.

Comment: (cont ...) Here is a couple of test cases with the junk you selected: `if (matches = "asdf abcd  +=&^$#@.+)(*&".match(/\w+\b(?!$)/g))
   console.log( matches );`
and 
`if (matches = "asdf abcd  +=&^$#@.+)(*&".match(/\w+\b(?![^.,]?$)/g))
   console.log( matches );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var r = /\w+\b(?!$)/gm
var a = [
  "jumps over the lazy dog",
  "jumps over the lazy dog."
]

a.forEach(function(s) {
  var x = []
  while(m = r.exec(s)) {
    x.push(m[0])
  }
  console.log(x)
})
```

```
\w+\b(?!$)
```

- `\w+` Matches one or more word characters
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?!$)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not the end of the line

If you need to ensure the last word is followed by only `.` or `,`, you can use `\w+\b(?![^.,]?$)` instead. This will ensure that words at the end of the line that are not followed by `.` or `,` are excluded. Expand and run the following snippet to see this alternative method in practice.

```js
var r = /\w+\b(?![^.,]?$)/gm
var a = [
  "jumps over the lazy dog",
  "jumps over the lazy dog.",
  "jumps over the lazy dog;"
]

a.forEach(function(s) {
  var x = []
  while(m = r.exec(s)) {
    x.push(m[0])
  }
  console.log(x)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`(?![^,. ]+$)\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/NmxSOE/1)

Add char to be allowed at the end of the last word `[^,. ]`

Details:

- `(?!)` Negative Lookahead
- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `$` Asserts position at the end of a line

```js
function myFunction() {
console.clear();
  var re = /(?![^,. ]+$)\w+/g;
  var s = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var m;

  do {
      m = re.exec(s);
      if (m) {
          console.log(m[0]);
      }
  } while (m);
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:myFunction()">
  <input id="input" type="text" name="lastname" value="jumps over the lazy dog."><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It's much slower doing the final boundary check at the beginning of the word than after the word.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work `\w+\b(?=\W+\w|\s*[,.])`
but there are other ways I'm sure.

Formatted

```
 \w+ \b                 # word in string
 (?=                    # Check 
      \W+ \w                 # Not the last word
   |  \s* [,.]               # or, a word followed by a dot or comma
 )
```

```js
if (matches = "asdf abcd  +=&^$#@.+)(*&".match(/\w+\b(?=\W+\w|\s*[,.])/g))
   console.log( matches );
```